# Color thresholding function

Tags: python, performance, opencv

I wrote an adaptive color thresholding function in Python (because OpenCV's cv2.adaptiveThreshold didn't fit my needs) and it is way too slow. I've made it as efficient as I can, but it still takes almost 500 ms on a 1280x720 image. I would greatly appreciate any suggestions that will make this function more efficient!

Here's what the function does:

It uses a cross-shape of one-pixel thickness as the structuring element. For each pixel in the image, it computes the average values of `ksize` adjacent pixels in four directions **independently** (i.e. the average of `ksize` pixels in the same row to the left, in the same column above, in the same row to the right, and in the same column below). I end with four average values, one for each direction. A pixel only meets the threshold criterion if it is brighter than either both the left AND right averages or both the top AND bottom averages (plus some constant `C`).

I compute those averages incrementally for all pixels at the same time using `numpy.roll()`, but I still need to do this `ksize` times. The `ksize` will usually be 20-50.

Here is the code, the relevant part is really just what happens inside the `for`-loop:

```
def bilateral_adaptive_threshold(img, ksize=20, C=0, mode='floor', true_value=255, false_value=0):

    mask = np.full(img.shape, false_value, dtype=np.int16)

    left_thresh = np.zeros_like(img, dtype=np.float32) #Store the right-side average of each pixel here
    right_thresh = np.zeros_like(img, dtype=np.float32) #Store the left-side average of each pixel here
    up_thresh = np.zeros_like(img, dtype=np.float32) #Store the top-side average of each pixel here
    down_thresh = np.zeros_like(img, dtype=np.float32) #Store the bottom-side average of each pixel here

    for i in range(1, ksize+1): 
        roll_left = np.roll(img, -i, axis=1)
        roll_right = np.roll(img, i, axis=1)
        roll_up = np.roll(img, -i, axis=0)
        roll_down = np.roll(img, i, axis=0)

        roll_left[:,-i:] = 0
        roll_right[:,:i] = 0
        roll_up[-i:,:] = 0
        roll_down[:i,:] = 0

        left_thresh += roll_right
        right_thresh += roll_left
        up_thresh += roll_down
        down_thresh += roll_up

    left_thresh /= ksize
    right_thresh /= ksize
    up_thresh /= ksize
    down_thresh /= ksize

    if mode == 'floor':
        mask[((img > left_thresh+C) & (img > right_thresh+C)) | ((img > up_thresh+C) & (img > down_thresh+C))] = true_value
    elif mode == 'ceil':
        mask[((img < left_thresh-C) & (img < right_thresh-C)) | ((img < up_thresh-C) & (img < down_thresh-C))] = true_value
    else: raise ValueError("Unexpected mode value. Expected value is 'floor' or 'ceil'.")

    return mask
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution using `cv2.filter2D` that cuts the time to 25% of the original time:

```
def bilateral_adaptive_threshold_f2d(img, ksize=30, C=0, mode='floor', true_value=255, false_value=0):

    mask = np.full(img.shape, false_value, dtype=np.int16)

    left_thresh = cv2.filter2D(img, ddepth=cv2.CV_32F, kernel=np.ones((1,ksize+1)), anchor=(ksize,0), delta=0, borderType=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT)
    right_thresh = cv2.filter2D(img, ddepth=cv2.CV_32F, kernel=np.ones((1,ksize+1)), anchor=(0,0), delta=0, borderType=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT)
    up_thresh = cv2.filter2D(img, ddepth=cv2.CV_32F, kernel=np.ones((ksize+1,1)), anchor=(0,ksize), delta=0, borderType=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT)
    down_thresh = cv2.filter2D(img, ddepth=cv2.CV_32F, kernel=np.ones((ksize+1,1)), anchor=(0,0), delta=0, borderType=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT)    

    left_thresh /= ksize
    right_thresh /= ksize
    up_thresh /= ksize
    down_thresh /= ksize

    if mode == 'floor':
        mask[((img > left_thresh+C) & (img > right_thresh+C)) | ((img > up_thresh+C) & (img > down_thresh+C))] = true_value
    elif mode == 'ceil':
        mask[((img < left_thresh-C) & (img < right_thresh-C)) | ((img < up_thresh-C) & (img < down_thresh-C))] = true_value
    else: raise ValueError("Unexpected mode value. Expected value is 'floor' or 'ceil'.")

    return mask
```

Also, see the amazing response to this post for more details:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42540173/python-how-to-make-this-color-thresholding-function-more-efficient